# Heroku Postgres pg:backups Restore From Copy

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I suspect I already know the answer here, but wanted to confirm. When you use the command line interface for Postgres backups, the command `heroku pg:backups` returns a list of Backups, Restores, and Copies. Apparently, my daily backups routine stopped working somewhere along the way, so my backups list was empty. I did, however, see this:

[image]

My suspicion is that this is merely a historical record showing that a copy was performed, however, I was hopeful that maybe I would be able to recover the database from that point in time. The restore command doesn't work with that ID, though. It gives me:

[image]

Can anyone confirm that this copy can or cannot be recovered?